Wifi/LAN stops working randomly
Problem Behavior:

Internet on my PC stops working randomly. This happens both with WiFi and LAN.

I have seen that once the computer locks/goes to sleep, I am unable to access internet.

I can access my local NAS but internet doesn't work.

I have to restart to activate internet again.

If I shut down and start again, the internet doesn't work, it need to do a RESTART explicitly.

The internet works fine on all my other devices.


System Configuration:
OS:

Windows 11 Pro

Version: 10.0.22631 Build 22631


No updates available as on 20 Jun 2024
WiFi Card:

RZ608 Wi-Fi 6E 80MHz (MediaTek)

Driver Version: 3.3.0.972


LAN NIC:

Intel Ethernet Controller I225-V

Driver Version: 2.1.4.3


PC Hardware:

Minisforum UM690

Ryzen 9 6900 HX


Other details (Might be relevant):

Using Tp-Link's Dec XE75 as my mesh router

ATT's modem

Firewalla Gold SE as my firewall.

LAN is connected to my PC via one of the satellite device.

I am either connected to LAN or Wi-Fi, not using both at same time.


Solutions Tried so far:

Reinstalling Windows

(Both for LAN & Wi-Fi) Under Device Management -> Power Management -> "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" has been unchecked.

Updating driver to the latest version.

Disabling and Enabling Network Adaptors.

Un installing and reinstalling network adaptors.


Any help is appreciated, its really getting difficult to work and attend meetings.
Thank you in advance.

See if https://superuser.com/questions/1037843/make-windows-10-connect-disconnect-to-wifi-based-on-ethernet-connection-status helps with the Win  11-specific answer.
